# SXA update SXA content Powershell script results toolbar missing

Tags: sxa, upgrade

Upgrading from `9.0.2` to `10.2`. After installing the latest `SXA package`, I see the yellow warning bar

```
You must upgrade the SXA content.
```

When I click the `Upgrade` link, the script runs and then I get the `Powershell Script Results` dialog. It lists the needed tasks ok, but at the top of the dialog, between the black title bar and the light blue information bar that says

```
`Upgrade steps pending`
```

there should be a `toolbar/ribbon` ("Actions") with two buttons (**Upgrade** and **Express Upgrade**).  In my case, this is not displaying.  I've tried in `Chrome, Edge`, and `Firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

So just digging around, I found this.

In the content tree, navigate to `/sitecore/system/modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA-Upgrade/Functions`. Right-click on **Run Upgrade**. Click **Edit with ISE**. Click **Execute**.

`PowerShell` Script Results dialog now opens with the tool ribbon visible and I was able to complete the upgrade.